# enron email analysis in R

Tags: r

I was trying to follow instructions from here: 
https://rpubs.com/pprevos/enron

and when I ran:

```
#Create list of sender and receiver (inbox owner)
inboxes <- data.frame(
  from=apply(as.data.frame(emails), 1, function(x){readLines(x, warn=F)[3]}),
  to=emails, 
  stringsAsFactors=F
  )
```

I got this error:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :

 Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how this can be fixed?

Edited to add:

To read the file in, I ran this code and got the same numbers listed in the tutorial so I thought (probably inaccurately) that it was correct.

```
# Enron Email Dataset: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~./enron/
download.file("http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~enron/enron_mail_20150507.tar.gz", destfile = "enron_mail_20150507.tar.gz")
untar("enron_mail_20150507.tar.gz")

# E-mail corpus consists of nested folders per user with e-mails as text files
# Create list of all available e-mails

emails <- list.files("maildir/", full.names = T, recursive = T)
length(emails)
# Filter by inbox only
emails <- emails[grep("/inbox", emails)]
length(emails)
```

Comment: What did you do to read the file? Are you *sure* the file is where you're directing your code to?

Comment: Edited above to address this. thank you for your question

Answer (score 0):

Your code should not produce this error if you first executed the reading part, then the `data.frame` part.
The 2 most likely reasons why this error occurred are:

1. After un-taring the archive, you decided that the folder was too big, and you moved it manually to another location.
2. After un-taring the archive, you changed your R session's working directory.

This code works:

```
# The OP's data loading
download.file("http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~enron/enron_mail_20150507.tar.gz", destfile="enron_mail_20150507.tar.gz")
untar("enron_mail_20150507.tar.gz")
emails <- list.files("maildir/", full.names=T, recursive=T)
inbox <- emails[grep("/inbox", emails)]

# The following part can be replaced with the OP's code
library(data.table)
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)
my_mapper_function <- function(path) {
    input <- readLines(path, warn=FALSE)
    from <- input[grepl("^From: .*([a-zA-Z0-9.'_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.'_-]+).*$", input)] %>% 
        gsub("From: ", "", .) %>% head(1)
    folder <- path %>% 
        gsub("maildir//", "", .) %>% 
        gsub("/.*$", "", .)
    to <- input[grepl("^To: .*([a-zA-Z0-9.'_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.'_-]+).*$", input)] %>% 
        gsub("To: ", "", .) %>% paste(collapse="")
    subject <- input[grepl("^Subject: ", input)] %>% 
        gsub("Subject: ", "", .) %>% head(1)
    
    data.table("File"=path, "Folder"=folder, "From"=from, "To"=to, "Subject"=subject)
}

inboxes <- map(inbox, my_mapper_function) %>% rbindlist(fill=TRUE)
```

Note that the code in `my_mapper_function` has many flaws, I just tried to give you a lead on a cleaner way to iterate over those file names to create a table structure with information about each email. The problem with your approach is that you'd have to read each file several times, one for each information that you want to extract.